# Looking for a humorous sci-fi story about puns

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

I'm thinking of a very short story that ran in one of the big science fiction magazines--Asimov's or Analog, probably--maybe a decade or so ago, about a disease epidemic that created puns. Anybody know what it was? Thanks!

Comment: There was a very long-running series of very short, punch-line stories, always written to include a character named Ferdinand Feghoot (often with a large generational number, like DMXCVII); the stories are called Feghoots.  Every single one ended with a pun of some kind, and the name Feghoot came to be associated with this kind of story.  I wonder if yours wasn't a Feghoot about Feghoots...

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon: I see what you did there.

Comment: Another possibility is Asimov's Jokester, which involved MULTIVAC realizing that jokes were an alien experiment. Also, there's a real life form of brain damage, Witzelsucht, that causes people with it to constantly make jokes and puns, but it's not a disease that spreads.

Comment: Blimey! While googling in search of an answer, I found out that there is actually a disease/disorder that causes puns! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witzelsucht
I wonder if Spider Robinson has it?